# I can not make the correct linq request

Tags: c#, linq

I form a request, it works.

```
var query = db.Persons.Where(p => p.Date == "27.02.2020").Where(p => p.Country == "USA");
```

But since I will need to use it in if-else
I changed it a little and now he just selects the last Where.

How can this problem be solved?

```
var query = db.Persons;

query.Where(p => p.Date == "27.02.2020");
query.Where(p => p.Country == "USA");
```

Comment: hmm.. strange just tried and stumbled upon an IQueryable conversion error

Answer (score 0):

The [`Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.8) method, like all LINQ methods, does not modify the source enumerable in-place, but instead returns a new enumerable that has the operation, or in this case filter, applied to it.

That means you need to assign the result of each operation back into your variable for it to persist. The following should be equivalent to your original snippet:

```cs
IQueryable<Person> query = db.Persons;
query = query.Where(p => p.Date == "27.02.2020");
query = query.Where(p => p.Country == "USA");
```

As pointed out in the comments, the `query` variable type now needs to be compatible with both the type of `db.Persons` *and* the return type of `Where`.

Comment: `var` should be changed into `IQueryable<Person>`. That's what `Where` returns.

Comment: It really should be `IQueryable<Person>`, otherwise the rest of the query won't be translated into SQL but executed in memory. `IQueryable` basically is an expression that can be extended  and _then_ translated.

Comment: @GertArnold Ok, sorry about that. I only have experience with using LINQ on in-memory collections, and wasn't sure `db.Persons` would implement `IQueryable<Person>`, so I thought I would make a safe bet. This time, I just went ahead and do what you said :)